# I couldn't open database file .bib : \bibdata{ : }

Tags: latex, biblatex

So we changed our LaTeX file from a regular style to an Elsevier style, but the bibliography does not get added to the file. Judging from the error statement I used as the title, I believe it has to do with this error message. I have made multiple attempts by e.g. changing the name of the bibliography, forcing it in etc. and yet it does not show.

Can anyone help me out?

This what I have used:

```
% Loading bibliography style file

%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}

\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}

% Loading bibliography database

\bibliography{cas-refs}
```

where cas-refs.bib is the bibliography file.

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] that allows us to reproduce the problem

Comment: Please also show the complete error message